# Where can I find table and field specs on the existing tables in Business Central?

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm trying to create Relations to fields in other tables from the standard BC install.

For example adding a table with a field having a Relation to the UOM table in Business Central.

From my current knowledge, what I'm seeeing, on the table list, what shows is the table caption, where can I find the full list of specs on the built-in tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few methods you can use:

1. If you use docker and have created a container with BcContainerHelper to download symbols from you will have the folder `C:\bcartifacts.cache` which will contain the source code for the version you are developing against.
2. The Visual Studio Code extension `AZ AL Dev Tools/AL Code Outline` has a feature that will display the objects in a given symbols file. You can then navigate from an object to the source code. All you need to do is install the extension in Visual Studio Code and then click the relevant symbols file in your `.alpackages` folder.